# include latex table in rmarkdown

Tags: markdown, threeparttable

I try to include latex code (a table) into my Rmarkdown document. I need to use latex instead of other options because the table has to be in a certain format.

The problem I encounter is the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Environment threeparttable undefined.
>   Error: Failed to compile confounder_table.tex. See
>   confounder_table.log for more info.  Execution halted

This is the table I include in the .Rmd document. I want to render it to pdf and/or docx and I use knitr for that (all in Rstudio). After working on that for 2 hours I hope that you can give me a hint how to solve this. It works for docx and html but not for the pdf format.

This is table code:

```
\begin{table}[tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descriptive statistics included in the present study.}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
cyl & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Some columnname}\\
\midrule
4.00 & 26.66 \&plusmn; 4.51\\
6.00 & 19.74 \&plusmn; 1.45\\
8.00 & 15.1 \&plusmn; 2.56\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
\textit{Note.} There were no signnificant differences in the means between the groups.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, I just use escape to latex in `pandoc`-flowered markdown.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using bookdown, there is explicit functionality to handle this. You just need to handle the LaTeX with the following:

> ```{=latex}
>
> ```
>          [PUT LATEX HERE]
> ```
>
> ```

**This feature requires a Pandoc version higher than 2.0 (check `markdown::pandoc_version()`).**

If you have the right pandoc version, you would do:

> ```{=latex}
>
> \begin{table}[tbp]
> \begin{center}
> \begin{threeparttable}
> \caption{Descriptive statistics included in the present study.}
> \begin{tabular}{ll}
> \toprule
> cyl & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Some columnname}\
> \midrule
> 4.00 & 26.66 &plusmn; 4.51\
> 6.00 & 19.74 &plusmn; 1.45\
> 8.00 & 15.1 &plusmn; 2.56\
> \bottomrule
> \addlinespace
> \end{tabular}
> \begin{tablenotes}[para]
> \textit{Note.} There were no signnificant differences in the means between the groups.
> \end{tablenotes}
> \end{threeparttable}
> \end{center}
> \end{table}
>
> ```

Here's an example using the bookdown package for longer documents: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html

Comment: Is it available only for PDF output?

Comment: not working to export to MSWord. Would help to have a more expanded suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

I found the solution: I had to load a specific library for that with:

```
library(kableExtra)
```

Comment: Can you show your final code, please? I am having the same issue with a table I created myself, so I dont know how to use kableExtra in this case. Thanks